# How do I make my horizontal navigation panel rounded on both ends in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, rounded-corners

This is on my localhosted site and it's not available to watch. But here is a site with the same theme: [mladvisory.eu](http://mladvisory.eu)

When I try to round the button (the "Welcome"-button in link) with CSS code `border-radius`  it just creates a rounded sheet behind the actual button. So my question is: How do I change the button(the "Welcome"-button in link) to have rounded corners  rather than adding another one behind?

Here's the code that I want to add, but where do I write it?

```
.welcome { border-top-left-radius: 10px; }
.welcome:hover { border-top-left-radius: 10px; }
```

I want the top left corner on the left-button to be rounded and the top right corner on the right-button to be rounded.

I dont know any CSS, I just found this on the web.

Comment: the button? what button? where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

at no point is anything classed as welcome....

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul id="menu-menu" class="nav sf-menu">
        <li class="page_item page-item-9 current_page_item">
            <a href="http://mladvisory.eu/">Welcome</a>
        </li>
```

try:

```
ul#menu-menu li:first-child a {border-top-left-radius: 10px;}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. It worked out with just creating a 
#navigation li:first-child a {border-top-left-radius: 10px;} 
in the style.css